# Bourbon Refills Navigation IE Issue

Tags: bourbon

Is there anyway to correct the transparent lines from appearing under sub-menu items in Internet Explorer when using the navigation menu from Bourbon Refills?

Below is a screenshot of the issue present in the example on http://refills.bourbon.io:
[image]

Any tips or suggestions for correcting this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I determined the cause of these lines to be the border-top-left-radius and border-top-right-radius styles in the ul.submenu class. Commenting these lines out from the SCSS file and compiling a new navigation.css resolved this IE issue for me. See the commit below for more details. Thanks!
[image]